# How to click on image in action column of a grid view?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, extjs

This is for testing purposes through the javascript console. I have a grid view, I want to be able to click on the image that is located in the action column. Once clicked, it should remove the record from the grid. The image as an item ID associated with it. Here's my crack at it:

```
var getGridImg = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('actioncolumn[itemId=actionColumnID]')[0];
getGridImg.fireEvent('click', getGridImg);
```

This seems to not be working at all. ANY HELP?

I also tried this too, but after reloading the grid, the record is still there.

```
var getGridImg = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('actioncolumn[itemId=actionColumnID]')[0];
var store = getGridImg.getStore();
var record = getGridImg.store.getAt(0);   
store.remove(record);
```

Here's my definition:

```
                    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                itemId: 'removeRecord',
                align: 'right',
                hidden: true,
                width: 35,
                items: [{
                    icon: 'img.png',
                    handler: 'onRemoveRecord'
                }]
            }],
```

Comment: Show your definition of the actioncolumn. The shown parts of the code do not expose the problem.

Comment: Which version of ext are you using? I did not get a string working as a handler in ExtJS 4.2.2, but functions work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler inside your actioncolumn definition's item object:

```
{
    xtype:'actioncolumn',
    width:50,
    items: [{
        icon: 'path/to/your/image.png',  
        tooltip: 'A tooltip message',
        handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
           // your code goes here
        }
    }]
}
```

Please refer to official [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action) for more details

Comment: it does have an handler. I'm checking this for testing purposes from the java script console.

Comment: try mentioning that in your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following pattern for all of my action column icons. See if this helps. I am not sure I follow your JS console requirement. Hope this helps.

In your view (grid for e.g. with xtype: 'yourgrid'):

```
 {
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            flex:1,
            items: [{
                iconCls: 'icon-add',
                // You will need a class icon-add in your css file
                handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    this.up('grid').fireEvent('buttonclick', grid, rowIndex, colIndex);
                }
            }
            ]
},
```

In your controller for this view:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'yourgrid':{
            buttonclick : this.buttonclick
        }
    });
},
buttonclick: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
    var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex), me = this;
    //delete from server
     grid.mask("Deleting..");
     rec.destroy({
            scope:this,
            callback : function(record, operation) {
                 if (operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                            grid.getStore().reload();
                 } else {
                      Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error','Error while deleting record\n'+operation.response.responseText);
                 }
                grid.unmask();
           }
    });
   //if you like to just remove it from the store you could use grid.getStore().removeAt(rowIndex);
},
```

In your css file:

```
.icon-add {
     background-image: url(/images/add_icon.png) !important;
     background-size: 14px 14px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

Comment: store.removeAt(0); only removes it from the grid, but once you reload the grid, the record is still there. @Vick L

Comment: store.removeAt(index) will remove the record from the store. Grid is just showing the records in that store. Grid does not really reload, it is the store that reloads and replenishes data in it from the server (or some static data).  My example shows a destroy method which takes the record out from the server and hence when I call store reload server does not send that record back.

Comment: I've tried this and don't work, refresh grid and record still there.                                                                                                                  var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid[itemId=savedQueryGrid]')[0];
var record = grid.getStore().getAt(0);
var store = grid.getStore(); grid.store.destroy(record);